# adding multiple String values in arraylist at a single index and write on file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to store more than 1 String value at a single 
index in my arraylist. i try the folowing code but it cannot print the desired output.it only write A input on file  only and donot B and C input

```
    List<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>(2);

    String A=jTextField1.getText();
    String B=jTextField2.getText();
    String C=jTextField3.getText();

    String[] element1 = new String[] {A,B,C};  /// A,B,C is an input String
    arr.add(element1);

    try{
        FileWriter f1=new FileWriter("test.txt",true);
        try(BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(f1)){
            int sz=arr.size();
            for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
                out.write(arr.get(0)[i].toString()+"\n");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hint: look out for java coding styleguides, A, B, ... are simply bad names for variables. Then: why do you use lists to collect arrays? Why not use list of lsits?

Answer (score 2):

you are using for loop with the size of list variable. where the value of

```
int sz=arr.size(); //its is 1 because there is only 1 variable inside array list.
```

you need to use the below code to loop with the size of string array inside the list as below.

```
int sz=arr.get(0).length;
```

Comment: I try . the sz=3 . But loop execute only one time and write one element on file why???

Comment: for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
             {
             out.write(arr.get(j)[i].toString()+"\n");
             out.write(arr.get(j)[1].toString()+"\n");
             out.write(arr.get(j)[2].toString()+"\n");}   /// if i do this then it work

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(element1));
```

Comment: But he would have to change the List definition to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using arr.size() where arr is the arrayList. So, it will not be equal to the size of the string array. user the size of the String array. place

int sz=arr.get(0).length; instead of this.  int sz=arr.size();